# NCMBデータストア 更新方法について

Tags: javascript, monaca, angularjs, database

NCMB(nifty cloud mobile backend)で
オブジェクト更新方法が分からず困っております。

言語はJavaScriptです。（Monacaで開発しています）

取得・保存は問題なく出来ているのですが、更新が動作しません。
どこか誤っている箇所ございますでしょうか。ご教授の程よろしくお願い致します。

```
//tblhoge　name = "test" のオブジェクトを"test2"に更新

var tblHoge = ncmb.DataStore("tblhoge");
var hoge = new tblHoge();  

hoge.equalTo("name","test")
 .fetch()
 .then(function(results) {
 results.set("name","test2");
 return results.update();
});
```

Comment: ぱっと見、動きそうにみえます。catch処理を追加してupdateで何かエラーが返ってきてないか確認されてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。解決しました！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var hoge = new tblHoge();
```

は、データストアにオブジェクトを保存する場合で、検索した結果に対して更新を行う場合は下記のようになります。

```
var tblHoge = ncmb.DataStore("tblhoge");
tblHoge.equalTo("name", "test")
    .fetch()
    .then(function(results) {
        results.set("name", "test2");
        return results.update();
    });
```

Comment: 上記の通り修正したところ、動作するようになりました。ご回答ありがとうございました！

Comment: 解決済み(回答左のチェック)にしていただけると助かります。